# Spark Maven Project - Dockerize my application - Cannot recognize Spark libraries on docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, apache-spark

I have a Java project that runs a java spark script. If I run my script locally as Java application, it runs without any problems but once I pass to a docker it gives me the following problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession
```

My pom.xml is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.script</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>spark</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                  <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                          <finalName>my.script.spark</finalName>
                          <archive>
                            <manifest>
                              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                              <mainClass>my.script.spark.App</mainClass>
                              <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                            </manifest>
                          </archive>
                        </configuration>
                      </plugin>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                          <finalName>my.script.spark</finalName>
                          <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                          </descriptorRefs>
                          <archive>
                            <manifest>
                              <mainClass>my.script.spark.App</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                          </archive>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have a docker file to build my container:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/my.script.spark.jar my.script.spark.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","my.script.spark.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

So then I can call the container through a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  the_spark:
      image: user/my_spark
      container_name: my_spark
```

But once I make my docker compose-up, the spark container gives me that log, and I cannot know how to force the spark installation. I already make the maven install and build using eclipse.

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks